# How to force Excel 2016 to ask about encoding when opening a TSV file with a double-click?

Tags: microsoft-excel, encoding

I have a UTF8 TSV file that contains text in various languages. If I start Excel 2016, then go to Open and then select the file, Excel will ask me about the encoding of the file, at which point I can choose UTF8 and open the document properly.

However, if I simply double-click on the TSV file, it opens it up without asking me about encoding, guesses it wrong and garbles the foreign-language text. How can I force it to ask me about encoding when opening a file this way?

Windows 10, in case it matters.

Answer (score 0):

[It seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155097/microsoft-excel-mangles-diacritics-in-csv-files) that you should be able to make it work if your TSV file has a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). It essentially add encoding information in a few bytes at the beginning, which many programs can read correctly (or skip).

Comment: So this means I need to add BOM to every TSV file before opening it. Unfortunately, this is not really a viable option for me: rather than having 1 file that I have to open many times, I have many files that I open once or twice. So messing with the BOM will take more time for me than just opening the doc manually as I described above.

Comment: There are tools that let you at least add the BOM easily (first hit on google http://www.radyakin.org/progs/bomtools/), though it's definitely an extra step to take. Unfortunately without BOM Excel defaults to the system locale's codepage...